# Owner - thunar with user permissions shows owner is root and with root shows owner is user - why?

Tags: usb, permissions

I installed 18 Studio recently.

When I insert particular USB stick (vfat type), I cannot make folders in root of USB. Owner of USB when checked by Thunar is root.

When I start Thunar by `sudo thunar` and check properties of USB stick, it says owner is my user name.

1. Why is that?
2. Why can't I make folders in root of USB (other USB - fuseblk type - allows that)?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem today, using Ubuntu Studio 18 and Thunar 1.6.15, but what I found out is that Thunar 1.6.15 seems to be affected by a bug in `glib`. This bug is said to be fixed in `glib-2.55` ([see here](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12541)).

However, to my understanding it seems that the fixed `glib` is not implemented in Thunar 1.6.15, but in v. 1.8.3, which is not available in Studio 18.

There is a way to install this via the experimental ppa at your own risk ([see here](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12859)).

The only way to solve the problem in Thunar 1.6.15 is to use `killall Thunar` ([see here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1021375/comments/114)).